# Getting error while implementing nodemailer to send mail using Node.js

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I am trying to send email to user using `nodemailer` module using node.js but it's throwing the below error.

Error:

```
this.transporter.mailer = this;
                                ^

TypeError: Cannot create property 'mailer' on string 'SMTP'
    at Mail (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:45:33)
    at Object.module.exports.createTransport (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:46:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/heroku/FGDP/api/api.js:8:32)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
```

Here is my code:

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport("SMTP",{
    service: "Gmail",
    auth: {
        user: "subhrajyoti@gmai.com",
        pass: "***********"
    }
});
```

Here I need to send mail to the valid user but getting the above error.

Comment: According to [this documentation](https://nodemailer.com/smtp/), the first parameter is an javascript object and not the string "SMTP".

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct syntax is something like this

```
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
service: "Gmail",
auth: {
    user: "subhrajyoti@gmai.com",
    pass: "***********"
}
});
```

Comment: That was just an example. I meant to say you have to remove the "SMTP". It is not in the nodemailer doc

Answer (score 0):

```
// Use Smtp Protocol to send Email
      var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'smtp.mailgun.org',
        port: 25,
        secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
        auth: {
            user: "smtp username", 
            pass: "smtp password" 
        }
      });
      var mail = {
          from: "From@gmail.com",
          to: "to@gmail.com",
          subject: "Your subject",
          text: "Node.js New world for me",
          html: "<b>Node.js New world for me</b>"
      }

      smtpTransport.sendMail(mail, function(error, response){
          if(error){
              console.log(error);
          }else{
                //console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
          }
          smtpTransport.close();
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

set your nodemailer config like this.

```
let nodemailerConfig = {
    host:"smtp.gmail.com" ,
    port: 465,
    secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SMTP_USERNAME,
      pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD
    }
}
```